# Accessing image url in Strapi

Tags: node.js, strapi

I'm having some serious difficulties accessing my images from Strapi, and everything that I've come across on here just says to add 'http://localhost:1337' before accessing the URL but that's not working for me. I'm super confused as to whats going and I also don't understand why it's so difficult to access them in the first place?

```
// constants
const strapi = 'http://localhost:1337/posts'
const rootNode = document.getElementById('root');
const api_url = "http://localhost:1337"


function generateHTMLtemplate(data) {
  
  // let url = JSON.stringify(data.image.formats.small.url)
  // console.log(url)
  // ^this returns "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'url')"

  // console.log(api_url + url)
  // ^this also returns "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'url')"

  const { title, description } = data
  return `
    <div class="time-card-header">
    <header class="time-card-header">
    <div class="header-content">
    <h4 class="timeline-title"><span class="badge">${title}</span></h4>
    <p>${description}</p>
    <div class="circle">
 
    <img src=>
    
    </div>
    </div>
    </header>
     <div class="line"></div>
   </div>
`
}

// render to the dom

function renderDataToTheDom(node, data) {
  const html = data.map(item => generateHTMLtemplate(item)).join('')
  console.log(html)
  node.innerHTML = html
}

// renderDataToTheDom(root, [1,2,3])

async function getData(url) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url)
    const data = await response.json();
    renderDataToTheDom(root, data)
  } catch (error){ 
  console.log("error", error.message)
  }
}


getData(strapi)
```

So I run into the issue as soon as I try to access the `.url`...

I would really appreciate any help on this, I've also tried to use an S3 plugin that I saw some people suggest but that didn't work either and I'd rather keep the solution as simple as possible as the site is a pretty simple one

my json:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "Title": "Santa Dog Picture",
    "published_at": "2021-03-29T02:45:32.389Z",
    "created_at": "2021-03-29T02:45:23.362Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-03-29T02:45:32.414Z",
    "Photo": {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Pets3.jpg",
        "alternativeText": "",
        "caption": "",
        "width": 4000,
        "height": 6000,
        "formats": {
            "thumbnail": {
                "name": "thumbnail_Pets3.jpg",
                "hash": "thumbnail_Pets3_a4be530d90",
                "ext": ".jpg",
                "mime": "image/jpeg",
                "width": 104,
                "height": 156,
                "size": 5.74,
                "path": null,
                "url": "/uploads/thumbnail_Pets3_a4be530d90.jpg"
            },
            "large": {
                "name": "large_Pets3.jpg",
                "hash": "large_Pets3_a4be530d90",
                "ext": ".jpg",
                "mime": "image/jpeg",
                "width": 667,
                "height": 1000,
                "size": 85.36,
                "path": null,
                "url": "/uploads/large_Pets3_a4be530d90.jpg"
            },
            "medium": {
                "name": "medium_Pets3.jpg",
                "hash": "medium_Pets3_a4be530d90",
                "ext": ".jpg",
                "mime": "image/jpeg",
                "width": 500,
                "height": 750,
                "size": 56.22,
                "path": null,
                "url": "/uploads/medium_Pets3_a4be530d90.jpg"
            },
            "small": {
                "name": "small_Pets3.jpg",
                "hash": "small_Pets3_a4be530d90",
                "ext": ".jpg",
                "mime": "image/jpeg",
                "width": 333,
                "height": 500,
                "size": 31.39,
                "path": null,
                "url": "/uploads/small_Pets3_a4be530d90.jpg"
            }
        },
        "hash": "Pets3_a4be530d90",
        "ext": ".jpg",
        "mime": "image/jpeg",
        "size": 2031.2,
        "url": "/uploads/Pets3_a4be530d90.jpg",
        "previewUrl": null,
        "provider": "local",
        "provider_metadata": null,
        "created_at": "2021-03-29T02:42:56.325Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-03-29T02:42:56.464Z"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

I had issues getting the image data on the API response. [This answer](https://forum.strapi.io/t/image-url-not-showing-on-api-call-strapi-v4/12956/2) on their forum helped.

Turns out Strapi auto filters relations.
To get relations if anyone is wondering is to use the populate field in the call.

Example to get all relations:

```
GET: /api/books?populate=*
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30592511)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this issue by calling the base url: `http://localhost:1337 + review.attributes.FeaturedImage.data.attributes.formats.thumbnail.url` which is http://localhost:1337/uploads/thumbnail_food_logo_61b7e1b311.webp?width=379&height=379

Comment: TY, took me way to long to figure this out, doesn't seem to be in the Strapi docs. For those struggling: in your Media Library plugin you can open the image and copy the link. Then you can get that image by calling the image name from the /uploads endpoint directly (not api)

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies in your json response. You don't have a key called `Image` in your response, rather it's called `Photo`. So all you need to do is access `Photo.url` and append the url to host `localhost:1337/`. Or if you wish to show the thumbnails, then you could use `Photo.formats.thumbnail.url` and append it similary to the host `localhost:1337`.

```js
// constants
const strapi = 'http://localhost:1337/posts'
const rootNode = document.getElementById('root');
const api_url = "http://localhost:1337"


function generateHTMLtemplate(data) {
  const { title, description, Photo } = data
  return `
    <div class="time-card-header">
    <header class="time-card-header">
    <div class="header-content">
    <h4 class="timeline-title"><span class="badge">${title}</span></h4>
    <p>${description}</p>
    <div class="circle">
 
    <img src="${api_url}/${Photo.url}"/>
    
    </div>
    </div>
    </header>
     <div class="line"></div>
   </div>`
}

// render to the dom
function renderDataToTheDom(node, data) {
  const html = data.map(item => generateHTMLtemplate(item)).join('')
  console.log(html)
  node.innerHTML = html
}

// renderDataToTheDom(root, [1,2,3])

async function getData(url) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url)
    const data = await response.json();
    renderDataToTheDom(root, data)
  } catch (error){ 
  console.log("error", error.message)
  }
}
```